# Reactjs sessionStorage null or undefine for first time app loading

Tags: reactjs

I am facing a weird issue i am setting a token to `sessionStorage` in `index.js` file

```
sessionStorage.setItem('authentication', keycloak.token);
sessionStorage.setItem('refreshToken', keycloak.refreshToken);
console.log('Test test Token details--------->' + sessionStorage.authentication);//Printing Saved token value
```

and trying to retrieve this value in another js which will do a nodejs restapi call

```
function getAll(pageNo, limit){
    return httpClient({
        url: `api/posts?page=${pageNo}&limit=${limit}`,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +sessionStorage.authentication,
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      },
    });
}
```

But after successfully login when first time app will render `sessionStorage.authentication` will pass `undefine` or `NULL` to nodejs api but when i will refresh the page by clicking `F5` it will pass token which i stored in `sessionStorage.authentication` variable .

I tried to add `waitBeforeShow={500}` but still same issue

```
 ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <App waitBeforeShow={500}/>
           
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById("root")
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

So this issue fixed
What was my code

```
ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <App waitBeforeShow={500}/>
           
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById("root")
    );

   sessionStorage.setItem('authentication', keycloak.token);
   sessionStorage.setItem('refreshToken', keycloak.refreshToken);
```

But as per the @ShinaBR2 [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62982328/how-to-get-value-from-reactjs-customhook/62982375?noredirect=1#comment111376668_62982375)

> I can have short answer because I'm on mobile now. Your problem might
> be the httpClient was initialized first. Then when user logged in, it
> doesn't re-initialize the httpClient. The token is saved after that,
> that's why it works after you hit F5.

I have to modify my code like this

```
    sessionStorage.setItem('authentication', keycloak.token);
    sessionStorage.setItem('refreshToken', keycloak.refreshToken);
    //React Render on authentication
   // ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
    ReactDOM.render(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <App waitBeforeShow={500}/>
           
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>,
      document.getElementById("root")
    );
```