# how to get value from reactjs customhook?

Tags: reactjs

I have a CustomHook something like this

```
import React from 'react';

export default function usePersistedState(key, defaultValue) {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(() => {
    const persistedState = localStorage.getItem(key);
    return persistedState ? persistedState : defaultValue;
  });
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, state);
  }, [state, key]);
  return [state, setState];
}
```

i am storing some token information

```
 usePersistedState('authentication', keycloak.token);
```

Now in service class i want to get the saved information
function GetToken(props) {
const token = usePersistedState(props,'test');
return token;
}

Same service class have

```
function getAll(pageNo, limit){
    return httpClient({
        url: `api/posts?page=${pageNo}&limit=${limit}`,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': 'Bearer ' +GetToken('authentication'),
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
      },
    });
}
```

But its failing .What is wrong with code and how to access the save data from custom hook?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can not use hook in a normal function, it can only be run in a function which return a React element or an HOC.

Comment: What is the other way to achieve it ? I am trying to resolve this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62973361/reactjs-sessionstorage-null-or-undefine-for-first-time-app-loading and newbie in react.

Comment: I can have short answer because I'm on mobile now. Your problem might be the `httpClient` was initialized first. Then when user logged in, it doesn't re-initialize the `httpClient`. The token is saved after that, that's why it works after you hit F5.

Comment: Thanks for your comment any idea what can be done to resolve the issue?